# Maytag Dryer LD69806AAE Doesn't Start

Tags: repair, dryer

We have a Maytag Dryer Model # LDG9806AAE in our rental property. Our tenant said it stopped working so I checked it out today. When I pressed the "power" button. I hear a buzzing sound but the drum doesn't tumble. Any suggestions for investigating before I call an appliance expert come and fix it? Are there belts? or a motor needs to be replaced? Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: If the motor is buzzing, check if it has a startup capacitor, those go bad in time preventing motor from starting.

Comment: A broken belt would allow the motor to spin but may sound like buzzing with no load.

Comment: https://youtu.be/gJwYV8HkTbk

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem and it turned out to be the thermal fuse. The thermal fuse helps prevent a dryer fire by shutting off power to the dryer if it gets too hot. If the clothes dryer will not start, examine this fuse. This is the most typical part to fail when the dryer won't work.

Comment: If the thermal fuse was blown/tripped, why would the dryer make a buzzing sound?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for others with the same problem...it can also be lint in the motor housing affecting the brushes and preventing it from starting up. Try pressing the door switch and rotating the drum by hand and see if it starts. If so, its probably lint in the motor.